# Are words in form of verbs and adjectives abstract concepts

Tags: semantics, cognitive-linguistics

There are concrete (like tree, dog) and abstract concepts (like war, love etc.).
I see that concept is expressed as a noun, but what about other parts of speech (verbs, adjectives, etc.)? Are they abstract concept or they became a concept when are changed to noun ?

Samples:

- know/knowing
- black/blackness

Are these 4 words above concepts or only those which are noun ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abstract vs concrete or figurative vs literal is a function of a word and its context, not of a dictionary entry lemma, a surface form or string literal like *tree* or *dog*.

For example, if we point to a tree in front of us and say "This tree grows all over the world", we do not literally mean this concrete tree.

There are also many tree concepts in mathematics and computer science, as well as books and other works by the name.

Conversely, we can say "His love smashed his car in an act of revenge" and then *love* is rather concrete.

So if we cannot without context say that a noun like *tree* is concrete or abstract, we cannot without context say that a verb or adjective like *to know* or *black* is concrete or abstract.

Comment: I think that in case of verbs (used to name actions), and adjectives (used to name quality) they can't be concrete independently of context - this is not a thing/entity. This is not about what I was asking, I wanted to know if surface form has matter, seems not. So are all verbs, adjectives, noun and other parts of speech a concepts or a concept can be only a noun ?

Comment: Yes, *can be concrete* is a useful question.  With the example *black*, we can nominalise it and then use it as a noun, including as a concrete noun.

Comment: What about words which express position, like: _in_, _on_, _above_ they are not concepts right ? They even can't be changed to noun. Is that true ?

Comment: That's a bit different, that's function words vs content words.  It's not true that they can never be changed to an adjective or noun.  *See the above*, or *I found an in*.  Again, these things are not tied to the exact string literal, which can be used in various, often evolving, ways.

Comment: One more question, so we can have two words which describe similar _thing_ : _live, _life_, sample: _My ilfe is good_. _I live well_. Are those two words describing two different concepts ? Are words (nouns, verbs, prepositions, pronouns) which have meaning a sample of some concept ?

Comment: They are different but (closely) related concepts, they are also different senses.  But this is interesting, I think this deserves a separate question.

Comment: I created separate question for this https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29121/words-and-concepts