# Relationship of senses across parts of speech

Tags: semantics, cognitive-linguistics

We can have two words which describe a similar concept but have different parts of speech, for example *live* V, *life* N.

> I live well.

Semantically similar or arguably equivalent construction:

> My life is good.

Are those two words describing two different concepts or not? Can words with different parts of speech constitute one concept?

This question came to my mind during reading the book *Cognitive Exploration of Language and Linguistics* by Rene Dirven, Marjolijn Verspoor.

Comment: Continuation of https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/are-words-in-form-of-verbs-and-adjectives-abstract-concepts/28905.

Comment: Original sample from the mentioned book (page 15). 

"a. Look at that rain !
b. It's raining again. 
c. And the rain, it raineth every day. 

In all three sentences we have chosen the same lexical category _rain_, but it is construed as two diﬀerent word classes, as a noun in (15a) , as a verb in (15b) and both as a noun and a verb according to Shakespeare in (15c)". 

For me is a little unclear what authors mean by term **lexical category**.

Answer (score 2):

These words are related by [**derivation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_derivation).  In each case, one of the parts of speech was first.  Then others were created from one or more of its senses, but can then take on a semantic life of their own.

(In English it is very subtle because the surface forms are identical or, in your *life* N / *live* V / *live* ADJ example, very similar and the derived by a process that is no longer productive.)

Because of constant semantic shift, the senses are hardly ever 1:1 even on day one, so it is dangerous to define concepts as if they are logical and orderly, not fuzzy and tangential.

*live* ADJ is in the same semantic field as *television* and *concert*, but in some other languages *live* in the sense of *television* is literally *direct ether*, and literally *alive* or *living* is only used for *in-person performance* as opposed to something remove.

(In English it's a bit hard to make this distinction, so for example in a café full of screens showing the Eurovision final in real time, it's *live* but not *live*.)

This hints at us that this sense of *live* is not very tightly bound to *live* V, and, in fact, upon thought it's true, *show* and *concert* have nothing special to do with *live* V or *life* N, nor with *lifer* or *leave*, which are also derived from the same root.

Another proof of this is that with enough derivations, we can get back to the same part of speech, yet they are not equivalent.   *lively* is not the same as *alive*, *enliven* is not the same as *live*, *liveliness* is not the same as *life*.

So dictionaries like Wiktionary take the safe route by listing a flat representation.  (A lemma can have multiple senses, a sense can only have one lemma.)

Comment: Can you mention 'lexeme' vs 'lemma'?

Comment: @aml Out of scope here, ask a separate question if wiki/Lexeme is not sufficient.

Comment: Scope was that *dictionary* lemma is narrower than lexeme, but *psycholinguistic* lemma is broader than lexeme.  Probably is worth a question.

Comment: I'm confused on how morphological derivation applies in cases where there are no affixes.

Comment: If no visible affixes exist, sometimes "zero-affixes" (affix "Ø") are used to mark different types of the same surface form as morphologically derived from a base form.

Comment: @jeffschneider There are all those cases like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun - no affix but still a derivation.  Now take it a step further, no sound change at all in the surface form, but it is still a derivation, not an equivalence.

Comment: Perhaps, 'morphological derivation' for those that use morphology, and 'zero-affix derivation' for those that don't?

Comment: @jeffschneider I think I'll just change it to *derivation*, although it does not have a separate Wikipedia article.